# 2種類のポインタを用いた線形リストの中央の要素の発見の仕方

Tags: アルゴリズム, データ構造

長さが未知の線形リストの中央の要素はどのようにして見つければよいかという問題について、講義内で速いポインタと遅いポインタの2種類を使うことで見つけることが出来るという説明を講義内で受けたのですが、この速いポインタ、遅いポインタという概念について、解説がされている本やWebページなどがありましたら教えていただきたいです。

Comment: その線形リストが単方向なのか双方向なのか等、もうちょっと情報があると答えやすいでしょう。単方向リストを二度検索しないで中央を得る・・・ってことだと「速いポインタ＝１スキャンで１要素進む」「遅いポインタ＝２スキャンで１要素進む」を併用すると、速いポインタが末尾に届いたとき、遅いポインタは中央を指すっス。

Answer (score 1):

[Finding the Middle of a Linked List](https://dev.to/alisabaj/finding-the-middle-of-a-linked-list-36kp)は簡潔で分かりやすいかと思います。
`Fast and Slow pointer`といったキーワードで検索すると[Fast and Slow pointer pattern in Linked list](https://medium.com/@arifimran5/fast-and-slow-pointer-pattern-in-linked-list-43647869ac99)など他にも見つかります。

Comment: 後者のサイトが興味深いかも